# Replace XML tag via XSLT Mapping

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectInvoice type="INVOICE" xmlns="http://www.scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp">
<FileSize id="78447274">
<FileHeader>
  <FileNumber>15043662</FileNumber>
</FileHeader>
</FileSize>
</ConnectInvoice>
```

This need to be converted to below structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectInvoice type="INVOICE" xmlns="http://www.scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp">
<Invoice id="78447274">
<FileHeader>
<FileNumber>15043662</FileNumber>
</FileHeader>
</Invoice>
</ConnectInvoice>
```

Please note that value of "id" is dynamic.

Below XSLT mapping works fine if xmlns="http://www.scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp" is not present in the XML but XSLT doesn't do anything when the above xmls is in the XML. Can someone please help me fix my XSLT mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FileSize">
    <Invoice><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></Invoice>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks a lot

Update:

If i use below XSLT. The XML tag FileSize is getting replaced by Invoice (which is what i want) but i am also getting namespace in it (`<Invoice id="78447273" xmlns:sd="scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp">`)which i don't want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:sd="scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp"; xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">; 
<xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
<xsl:copy> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="sd:FileSize">
<Invoice><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></Invoice>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Try searching online for "XSLT namespaces" - the xmlns attribute you refer to declares that all elements are in a particular namespace, and your XSLT needs to reflect that. (I don't know the exact syntax, so don't bother asking; I'm just trying to give some pointers.)

Comment: Thanks . I updated the XSLT like :   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:sd="http://www.scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="sd:FileSize">
        <Invoice><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></Invoice>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet> . Now it is adding the namespace after Invoice as well : <Invoice id="78447273" xmlns:sd="http://www.scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp">

Comment: Please... _Do not post code like that in comments,_ ***it's unreadable***. If you have a clearer understanding of your question, [update the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32509696/edit).

Comment: @user2157477 Now that you have learned how to use a prefix when addressing nodes in a namespace, learn about the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below XSLT mapping works fine if xmlns="http://www.scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp" is not present in the XML but XSLT doesn't do anything when the above xmls is in the XML.

Actually, XSLT is doing a lot. Your example XSLT will process all nodes and copy all of them. But since there is no element mapping available, nothing else will happen.

An element name consists of a namespace binding and a local part. In your XSLT you only give the local part.

> xmlns:sd="scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp"

As you have meanwhile found out, you need to add the namespace.

> but i am also getting namespace in it

Yes, because it has now become part of the result. If a processor encounters namespace nodes, it will add them. The namespace fixup process takes care of a bit of the mess (preventing repetition, for instance), but can't do everything.

You need to help the XSLT processor by telling that you are (fairly) certain that certain namespace prefixes do not need to appear in the result (but if they are required, the processor will add them regardless):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:sd="scoobydoo.com/xml/ns/ocp" 
    xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="sd">
```

(I have removed your semicolons, as these are not allowed).

May I suggest taking a quick tour on the [basics of XML and later XSLT](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1)? It'll cost you only little time (you'll be amazed what Dimitre can teach you, even only the first hour is worthwhile!), but will save you countless of hours of frustration. XML and XSLT are mature technologies and like any other language out there, it takes some time to master them. A good tutorial or (mini)course can help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Abel and Michael. Adding the exclude-result-prefixes worked for me :)

Comment: @user2157477 you're welcome, glad we could be of help :)